# Adafruit SSD1306 scrolling function

Tags: arduino, oled, adafruit

There is a function in the Adafruit SSD1306 Library that prints a scrolling text. For example: `display.startscrollright(0x00,0x0F);` will print a text scrolling towards the right. What are the arguments "0x00" and "0x0F" for, and what kind of arguments are they?

Answer (score 6):

> display.startscrollright(0x00,0x0F); will print a text scrolling towards the right. What are the arguments "0x00" and "0x0F for and what kind of arguments are they?

The short answer is that those parameters define which parts of the display to scroll. Using `display.startscrollright(0x00,0x0F)` will scroll the whole display, as I explain below.

---

You can learn about this yourself in these steps:

1. Go to the [Adafruit SSD1306 Library source code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306).
2. Find the specific code for `display.startscrollright()` in `Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp`:

```
// To scroll the whole display, run: display.startscrollright(0x00, 0x0F) <-- SEE THIS!!
void Adafruit_SSD1306::startscrollright(uint8_t start, uint8_t stop) {
  TRANSACTION_START
  static const uint8_t PROGMEM scrollList1a[] = {
    SSD1306_RIGHT_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL,
    0X00 };
  ssd1306_commandList(scrollList1a, sizeof(scrollList1a));
  ssd1306_command1(start);
  ssd1306_command1(0X00);
  ssd1306_command1(stop);
  static const uint8_t PROGMEM scrollList1b[] = {
    0X00,
    0XFF,
    SSD1306_ACTIVATE_SCROLL };
  ssd1306_commandList(scrollList1b, sizeof(scrollList1b));
  TRANSACTION_END
}
```

**Notice** that `startscrollright(0x00,0x0F)` is specifically described in the code above as scrolling the whole display, so that might be all you were asking. But in case you wanted more explanation, read on.

From `Adafruit_SSD1306.h` see that:

`#define SSD1306_RIGHT_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL              0x26 ///< Init rt scroll`
and
`#define SSD1306_ACTIVATE_SCROLL                      0x2F ///< Start scroll`

As you see, the parameters `start` and `stop` are passed to the SSD1306 controller, as part of a `0x26` command sequence. Therefore...

3. Go to the [SSD1306 datasheet,](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf) and look at the commands (`0x26` and `0x2F`) being sent to that controller, by the Adafruit library code.
4. For example, in the datasheet, command `26h` (i.e. `0x26`) and its parameters are explained e.g.:

---

[image: Brief overview of horizontal scrolling setup command parameters from SSD1306 datasheet]

---

That part of the datasheet explains that command `26h` (i.e. `0x26`) sets up the horizontal scroll parameters and describes them.

Then command `2Fh` is also explained - this command actually starts the scrolling, after the setup has been done using command `26h` (or one of the other scrolling setup commands `27h, 29h, 2Ah`):

---

[image: Brief overview of activate scrolling command from SSD1306 datasheet]

---

Then look at this table for more details about command `26h`:

---

[image: Explanation of SSD1306 command 0x26 from its datasheet]

---

You can see that the two parameters `start` and `stop` from that routine in the Adafruit library are actually `B[2:0]` and `D[2:0]` in that description i.e. they select which pages of the GDDRAM (i.e. which parts of the display) are scrolled. See:

---

[image: Explanation of SSD1306 GDDRAM layout from its datasheet]

---

The datasheet includes this example of scrolling only *part* of the display to the right - in the example it is only `PAGE5` to `PAGE7` towards the bottom of the screen, which are scrolled:

---

[image: Example of horizontal scrolling command from SSD1306 datasheet]

---

So that is the whole story - the library routine passes those parameters to the SSD1306 horizontal scrolling setup command, to define which part of the display to scroll.